# How to access index number of a listView builder from outside the return function of itemBuilder?

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my list of items.

```
class MealsListData {
  String titleTxt;
  String startColor;
  String endColor;
  List<String> meals;
  int index;

  MealsListData({
    this.titleTxt = '',
    this.startColor = "#ffbf00",
    this.endColor = "#FFDF29",
    this.meals,
    this.index,
  });

  static List<MealsListData> tabIconsList = [
    MealsListData(
      titleTxt: 'Breakfast',
      meals: ["Bread", "Peanut butter", "Apple"],
      index: 1
    ),
    MealsListData(
      titleTxt: 'Lunch',
      meals: ["Salmon", "Mixed veggies", "Avocado"],
      index: 2
    ),
    MealsListData(
      titleTxt: 'Snack',
      meals: ["Recommend:", "800 kcal"],
      index: 3
    ),
  ];
}
```

I'm displaying a list of cards on the screen using ListView.
Each of the MealsListData values in the above code corresponds to one card.
What I want is when the user touches a card, that specific card should open up separately in a new window. 
The following is my ListView. I have wrapped mealsView widget indside an InkWell widget and used that as the return value of itemBuilder.
The original code did not have InkWell widget present.

```
ListView.builder(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 0, bottom: 0, right: 16, left: 16),
                    itemCount: mealsListData.length,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      var count =
                          mealsListData.length > 10 ? 10 : mealsListData.length;
                      var animation = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(
                          CurvedAnimation(
                              parent: animationController,
                              curve: Interval((1 / count) * index, 1.0,
                                  curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn)));
                      animationController.forward();

                      return InkWell( 
                                onTap: () {MyDiaryScreen2(
                                        itemIndex: MealsListData().index);
                                        print(MealsListData().index);},
                                child: MealsView(
                                    mealsListData: mealsListData[index],
                                    animation: animation,
                                    animationController: animationController,
                                    itemIndex: index,
                                  ));
                    }
                  ),
```

The following is the code of MealsView the class I'm using to get one card.

```
class MealsView extends StatelessWidget {
  final MealsListData mealsListData;
  final AnimationController animationController;
  final Animation animation;
  final int itemIndex;

  const MealsView(
      {Key key, this.mealsListData, this.animationController, this.animation, this.itemIndex})
      : super(key: key);

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: animationController,
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
        return FadeTransition(
          opacity: animation,
          child: new Transform(
            transform: new Matrix4.translationValues(
                100 * (1.0 - animation.value), 0.0, 0.0),
                //this is the individual card
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 200,
              child: 
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 32, left: 8, right: 8, bottom: 16),
                    child: Container(
                                   child: Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                           top: 22, left: 16, right: 16, bottom: 8),
                                        child: Column(
                                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                          Text(
                                            mealsListData.titleTxt,
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                          ),
                                       //Heading(Inside card) Style closed
                                          Expanded(
                                           child: Padding(
                                            padding:
                                             const EdgeInsets.only(top: 22, bottom: 8),
                                            child: Row(
                                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                              children: <Widget>[
                                               //this is the list of items
                                               Text(
                                                 mealsListData.meals.join("\n"),
                                               ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),                            
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),

                  ),                                

            ),
          )
        )
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

What am I doing wrong? When I tap on the cards the index number should be printed on debug console but all I get is NULL.

Comment: You are getting null because you are printing MealsListData().index and not the index returned by the builder

Answer (score -1, accepted):

instead of :

```
itemIndex: MealsListData().index);
print(MealsListData().index);}),
```

try

```
itemIndex: mealsListData[index]);
print(mealsListData[index]);}),
```

hope help you